# Counting if the word entered is a capital letter in a loop in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to that function that keeps prompting the user for words until they hit return. At that point, the program should return the number of upper-case words entered by the user.

What I have so far.

```
def upper():
    while True:
        x = input('Please enter word: ')
        if x.strip() == "":
            break
    print(len(x.split()))
upper()
```

How exactly would I count for capital letters each time it loops? I tried     print(len(x.split())) but that only returns zero for the last iteration.

-------------------------------edit

```
def upper():
    while True:
        x = input('Please enter word: ')
        if x.strip() == "":
            break
    capitalLetters = 0
    for letter in x:
        if letter.isupper():
            capitalLetters += 1
    upper()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution creates a list comprehension of the letters that are capital and then gets the length of that list

```
capitalLetters = len([letter for letter in x if letter.isupper()])
print(capitalLetters)
```

You could also use a regular for loop and loop through each letter and check if its capital, then increment a variable:

```
capitalLetters = 0
for letter in word:
    if letter.isupper():
        capitalLetters += 1
```

## For your code

```
def upper():
    while True:
        x = input('Please enter word: ')
        if x.strip() == "":
            break
        capitalLetters = 0
        for letter in x:
            if letter.isupper():
                capitalLetters += 1
        print(capitalLetters)
upper()
```

Comment: Is that implemented after the break?

Comment: You could put it before or after and it would still work, I think the best practice would be after though. Just make sure it's not inside the if statement.

Comment: I must be adding it incorrectly. I'm getting "NameError: name 'word' is not defined".

Comment: Change `word` to `x`. I just used a different variable name, x is ambiguous and doesn't describe itself.

Comment: I edited my code above with what you suggested but it's still skipping over it. Did I indent wrong or anything like that?

Comment: I'll edit my post to show you how it should look, your `upper()` shouldn't have been indented and your `for letter in x` needed to be indented one

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Here you go buddy

```
numUppers = lambda s: sum(map(lambda c: 65 <= ord(c) <= 90, s))
```

Comment: Why not `map(str.isupper, ...)`?

Comment: I like to give overly complex answers to homework questions, idunno.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is this:

```
count=0
countTotal=0
for c in x:
    if c >= 'A' and c <= 'Z':
        count++
countTotal += count
```

You need to make the count for each word entered, and then keep a countTotal variable to accummulate all the words' uppercases.